# sql How to cap the number of record when doing group by

Tags: sql, django

Suppose you have a 'like' rating records.

```
user document timestamp
```

You can see the count of ratings per each user

```
select user, count(user) 
from rating
group by user
```

what if you want the count but capped at some number like 100

```
select user, min(100, count(user))
from rating
group by user
```

How can you do something like above in sql, and preferably django queryset?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many databases support `least()` (which is what you want if you want an upper limit):

```
select user, least(100, count(*))
from rating
group by user;
```

If yours doesn't, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select user,
       (case when count(*) > 100 then 100 else count(*) end)
from rating
group by user;
```